# Automatic DATETIME value for empty object value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have `DATETIME` value in my database which is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by default, and this column can be empty.  When I try creating objects in PHP and inserting it into the database, it still asks me to insert that DATETIME value.

My question is: how can I insert object into database without defining that `DATETIME` value?  Shouldn't the database enter this value automatically?

When I am updating that object, I don't want to enter that value at all.

Comment: Leave the column from your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DEFAULT` keyword or do not specify that column at all:

```
CREATE TABLE myTab(i INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   b TEXT,
                   c TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO myTab(b, c)VALUES ('a', DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO myTab(b) VALUES ('b');

SELECT * FROM myTab;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/INKOE53714)**

Comment: I already have save(); function whats inserts data to database, but is there a way to insert that DEFAULT value in PHP? Otherwise it will be entered as string. For example: if I am giving values to object $object->date_added = DEFAULT?